# spring boot microservice one service call from another service as a project and response is not found in gardle multi module

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, microservices, spring-cloud

I have an spring boot microservice application in gradle project. So let's say my ms app number is two of product-service and order-service. And I have added in my order-service as a dependency of product-service. Everything is working fine apis, services etc. but when I send to order any product from order-service ms it's getting the exception as error message -> "Product not found" but in database product is exists. So to be more clearly lets following the code snippet.

**Product Entity**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "product", schema = "product")
@Builder
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Long productId;
    private String name;
    private long price;
    private long quantity;
}
```

**ProductRequest**

```
@Data
public class ProductRequest {
    private String name;
    private long price;
    private long quantity;
}
```

**ProductServiceImpl**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Log4j2
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
    private final ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Override
    public long addProduct(ProductRequest productRequest) {
        log.info("====> Adding product to database");
        Product product = Product.builder()
                .name(productRequest.getName())
                .price(productRequest.getPrice())
                .quantity(productRequest.getQuantity())
                .build();
        productRepository.save(product);
        log.info("====> Product added to database");
        return product.getProductId();
    }

    @Override
    public ProductResponse getProductById(Long productId) {
        log.info("====> Getting product from database");
        Product product = productRepository.findById(productId).orElseThrow(() ->
                new HandleProductNotFoundException("Product not found", "PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND"));
        return ProductResponse.builder()
                .productId(product.getProductId())
                .name(product.getName())
                .price(product.getPrice())
                .quantity(product.getQuantity())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void reduceQuantity(Long productId, Long quantity) {
        log.info("====> Reducing product {} quantity for product ID {}", quantity, productId);
        Product product = productRepository.findById(productId).orElseThrow(() ->
                new HandleProductNotFoundException("Product not found", "PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND"));
        if (product.getQuantity() < quantity) {
            throw new HandleProductNotFoundException("Product quantity is not enough", "PRODUCT_QUANTITY_NOT_ENOUGH");
        }
        product.setQuantity(product.getQuantity() - quantity);
        productRepository.save(product);
        log.info("====> Product quantity reduced");
    }
}
```

**ProductController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/product")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductController {
    private final ProductService productService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Long> addProduct(@RequestBody ProductRequest productRequest) {
        long productId = productService.addProduct(productRequest);
        return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create("/api/v1/product/" + productId)).body(productId);
    }
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<ProductResponse> getProductById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ProductResponse productResponse = productService.getProductById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(productResponse);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> reduceQuantity(@PathVariable("id") Long productId, @RequestParam Long quantity) {
        productService.reduceQuantity(productId, quantity);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

And when I send the request for reduce quantity from my ProductController everything is working fine. And this is my order-service ms following code snippet

**Order Entity**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_details", schema = "order")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private long productId;
    private long quantity;
    @Column(name = "order_date")
    private Instant orderDate;
    @Column(name = "order_status")
    private String orderStatus;
    private long amount;
}
```

**OrderRequest**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class OrderRequest {
    private long productId;
    private long quantity;
    private long totalAmount;
    private PaymentMode paymentMode;
}
```

**OrderServiceImpl**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {
    private final OrderRepository orderRepository;
    private final ProductService productService;
    @Override
    public long placeOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest) {
        productService.reduceQuantity(orderRequest.getProductId(), orderRequest.getQuantity());
        log.info("===> Creating order with status CREATED");
        Order order = Order.builder()
                .productId(orderRequest.getProductId())
                .quantity(orderRequest.getQuantity())
                .amount(orderRequest.getTotalAmount())
                .orderDate(Instant.now())
                .orderStatus("CREATED")
                .build();
        Order savedOrder = orderRepository.save(order);
        log.info("===> Order placed successfully with id: {}", orderRequest);
        return savedOrder.getId();
    }
}
```

and finally this is where I was trying to send the request from order service to product service, it throws the exception -> product not found. Where is the my mistake? Thank you in advance and order-service build.gradle file here is:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':product-service')
}

bootJar {
    enabled = true
    archiveFileName = "order.jar"
    mainClass = 'com.example.order.OrderApplication'
}

jar {
    enabled = false
}
```

**order service main class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example.product","com.example.order"})
public class OrderApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OrderApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**And one more thing I will tell before I forget I don't want to use feign client or any inter communication calling. I want to use common service that I mentioned before**